# Вызов контейнеров в тесте, с передачей параметров в конструктор

Tags: symfony3, php7, phpunit

Например, у меня есть сервисный класс `Facebook`, от которого наследуется множество других классов, которые я хочу протестировать. Сам класс `Facebook` наследуется от класса `AdsAbstract` с конструктором:

```
 public function __construct(ChannelSettingsManager $channelSettingsManager)
    {
        $this->channelSettingsManager = $channelSettingsManager;
    }
```

Как видим, в конструктор передается объект `ChannelSettingsManager`, у которого тоже есть конструктор:

```
   public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }
```

В `symfony` срабатывает автоподгрузка, благодаря которой нужные объекты подгружаются в конструктор.

Как мне создать экземпляр класса `Facebook` или любого другого, который от него наследуется, чтобы ему передались все нужные аргументы в конструктор?

Answer (score 1):

Я работаю с Symfony 4, не думаю, что сейчас есть большая разница, накидал вам простой пример

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MainTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testService()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $exceprionListener = self::$container->get('app.exceprion.listener');
    }
}
```

Маленькое пояснение для `self::$container->get('app.exceprion.listener');` - это имя сервиса из services.yml